# How to create two similar incremental game upgrades with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating an idle clicker game with html and JS, and I can't figure out how to make two similar upgrades. Here is the code I am using for it (https://codepen.io/samuelbeard/pen/Dsdie).

I also don't need the "Increase Clicks increment upgrade, I just want two different types of auto clickers, and once upgrade that increased the speed at which you automatically get "coins."

I am new to JS and html so I am sorry if I don't understand stuff.

Also, I'll attach a picture and what I have in html/css so far.

[image]

```html
<div>

    <center><b>Mining Enhancements</b></center>
    
    <p>
    </p>
    
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>Autoclicker</td>
          <td><span id="autoclicker_level">lvl 0</span></td>
          <td><button id="buy_click" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Buy for 1</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>Autoclicker 2</td>
          <td><span id="autoclicker_level_two">lvl 0</span></td>
          <td><button id="buy_click" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Buy for 1</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Speed up by 10%</td>
          <td><span id="speed_level">lvl 0</span></td>
          <td><button id="upgrade_speed" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Buy for 100</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: I decided to just remove that feature, so forget this question haha. I have a new problem though with a decimal click increment thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65988376/problem-occurs-when-changing-function-clickrate-to-decimal-form?noredirect=1#comment116670708_65988376