# Problem occurs when changing Function Clickrate to decimal form

Tags: javascript, html, css, decimal

I am trying to change the rate at which users receive "coins" on a incremental clicking game I am making, and I am having a problem where I want to make it so users only get fractions of coins when they click, but instead they are getting full coins. For example, I want to change it to 0.01 Coins Per Click, instead of 1. This is in Javascript and I cant quite figure out how to do this, so anything helps.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
<script>
//variables
var clicks = 0; //increment this by one every click
var auto_clicks = 0; //automatically click once per second
var cost = 1; //the cost of this should increase exponentially
var upgrade_speed = 0; //the level of the speed up upgrade
var click_rate = 1000; //ms between each autoclick
var interval_auto; //storing our interval here so we can update it
var click_increment = 1; //how many clicks per click
//functions

function update_total_clicks() { //updates the number of clicks   
    var e = document.getElementById("total_clicks");
    e.innerHTML = clicks;
}

function buy_something(c, button) {
    if (clicks < c) {
        button.className = 'btn btn-danger';
        setTimeout(function() {
            var e = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-danger")[0];
            e.className = 'btn btn-success';
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }
    clicks -= c;
    return true;
}

function update_workers() {
    var e2 = document.getElementById("time_period");
    e2.innerHTML = parseFloat(click_rate / 1000.0).toFixed(2);
    clearInterval(interval_auto);
    interval_auto = setInterval(function() {
        clicks += auto_clicks;
        update_total_clicks();
    }, click_rate);
}
//click events
document.getElementById("click").onclick = function() {
    clicks = parseFloat(clicks) + parseFloat(click_increment);
    update_total_clicks(); //updates the text
};
document.getElementById("buy_click").onclick = function() {
    if (!buy_something(cost, this)) return;
    auto_clicks++;
    cost = Math.pow(2, auto_clicks); //new cost
    update_total_clicks();
    var e = document.getElementById("clicks_per_second");
    e.innerHTML = auto_clicks;
    var e2 = document.getElementById("buy_click");
    e2.innerHTML = 'Buy for ' + cost;
    var e2 = document.getElementById("autoclicker_level");
    e2.innerHTML = 'lvl  ' + auto_clicks;
};

document.getElementById("upgrade_speed").onclick = function() {
    var upgrade_cost = (Math.pow(3, upgrade_speed)) * 100;
    if (!buy_something(upgrade_cost, this)) return;
    upgrade_speed++;
    click_rate = click_rate * 0.90;
    update_workers();
    var e2 = document.getElementById("upgrade_speed");
    e2.innerHTML = 'Buy for ' + ((Math.pow(3, upgrade_speed)) * 100);
    var e2 = document.getElementById("speed_level");
    e2.innerHTML = 'lvl  ' + upgrade_speed;
};


//Start Autoclickers
update_workers();

function set_cookie(cookie_name, value) {
    expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setTime(new Date().getTime() + (10 * 60 * 1000));
    var c_value = escape(btoa(JSON.stringify(value))) + "; expires=" + expiry.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cookie_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function get_cookie(cookie_name) {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + cookie_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(cookie_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1) return false;
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
    if (c_end == -1) {
        c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = atob(unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end)));
    return JSON.parse(c_value);
}

</script>
```

I know this is really long, sorryyyy.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work ? Where are you changing the `click_increment` ? Because changing it at the top, it works alright on my side.

Comment: It works up until 0.05, and then it goes to adding like 20 more decimal spots on the back.

Comment: Also I am changing "var click_increment = 1; //how many clicks per click" to "var click_increment = 0.01; //how many clicks per click" that, if that helps haha.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that your code is not working, the problem lies with floating point arithmetic precision on computers. The example of `0.05 + 0.01` is well known, as for `0.1+0.2`. You can try it directly in the console, it will do the same.

To know more about this, have a look at [Why does adding two decimals in Javascript produce a wrong result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3439040/2667536). This resource is especially good at explaining simply the matter: https://floating-point-gui.de/. Short summary:

> Internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point) that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small rounding error even before the calculation happens.

For your specific problem, you can use `toPrecision` or `toFixed` to round the `clicks` variable and remove extra digits.

Comment: Ah ok thank you! I ended up fixing it by using:

Comment: function update_total_clicks() { //updates the number of clicks   
    var e = document.getElementById("total_clicks");
    e.innerHTML = ((clicks * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}

Comment: But I now cant figure out how to change the clicks per second to 0.01 when someone has bought an auto clicker. Here is my code: https://codepen.io/samuelbeard/pen/Dsdie